# Access 2016 - using contents of TextBox in SQL Update command

Tags: ms-access

Receiving error message 'Runtime Error 3061: Too few parameters. Expected 1'

This code fails:

```
dbs.Execute "UPDATE Master " _
    & "SET Selected = -1, tmpListName=Me.inpListName.Value " _
    & "WHERE Active = -1 ; "
```

inpListName is an unbound TextBox in the form header.

This code works:

```
dbs.Execute "UPDATE Master " _
    & "SET Selected = -1, tmpListName='some value' " _
    & "WHERE Active = -1 ; "'
```

Code is attached to button onclick in header of form.

Thanks in advance for any help here.

regards
Alan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
dbs.Execute "UPDATE Master " _
    & "SET Selected = -1, tmpListName='" & Me.inpListName.Value & "' " _
    & "WHERE Active = -1 ; "
```